# phow_caltech101 to change categories in matlab (vlfeat)

Tags: matlab, vlfeat

I'm studying the [Caltech101 computer vision dataset](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/) using Matlab..

I wanted to classify and train the images of caltech-101 using `phow_caltech.m` file

but there was a problem, I don't know how to change the categories...

these are what I did.

1. setup lv_setup
2. test version : vl_version verbose OK
3. vl_demo OK
4. make m_file phow_caltech101.m (copy)
5. I downloaded caltech101 images at [here][2]  by myself and copied to `data/caltech-101`
6. `>>phow_caltech101` (in command widnow)

   - I saw fixed example categories (BACKGROUND_Goole, Faces, Faces_easy, Leopards, Motobikes)

I've tried to change the example categories(BACKGROUND_Goole, Faces, Faces_easy, Leopards, Motobikes)

I want to use categories ( accordion, airplanes, anchor, ant in caltech-101)

I changed some codes of phow_caltech101.m but it didn't work...

plz give me some advice ... help me

I look forward to replying your mail or answer thank you~!

[this is phow_caltech101 code](http://www.vlfeat.org/applications/caltech-101-code.html)

C:\VLFEAT\data\caltech-101 ( there are many image folders )

conf.calDir = 'data/caltech-101' ; ( I changed like this in phow_caltech101.m file)

Comment: "but it didn't work" is not very informative. If you want advice given that little info? Try harder.

Comment: "it didn't work" meaning is not thing has changed, actually I changed conf.numClasses numbers and conf.prfix but it still appears the example categories(BACKGROUND_Goole, Faces, Faces_easy, Leopards, Motobikes), I want to change the categories...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help header to `phow_caltech101`:

> The program can also be used to train a model on custom data by pointing CONF.CALDIR to it. Just create a subdirectory for each class and put the training images there. Make sure to adjust
>   CONF.NUMTRAIN accordingly.

Create a folder (say `'data/myclasses'`) containing the new classes (image collections) and have `conf.caldir` point to it, in `phow_caltech101.m`. That should be the first thing you change. There should be no need to change `conf.prefiX` if you are still putting the classes under `data/....` but you need to adjust `conf.numtrain` to be the number of training sets you want to use.

caveat: my answer is based entirely on the documentation, I have not run the software.

**Edit**

Rather than attempt to run the script directly, start by trying to run the following lines at the matlab prompt, to check that you set up your folders correctly:

```
% the following line should contain the path to your data...
conf.calDir = 'data/caltech-101'; % <-- change this line if necessary

% make sure matlab finds the folder with your data
exist(conf.calDir, 'dir') % should return a "1"

% check the contents of the calibration data folder
classes = dir(conf.calDir)
```

If the folder does not exist or the contents being listed as `classes` are incorrect you need to adjust `conf.calDir` or the location of your data.

Comment: C:\VLFEAT\data\caltech-101 ( there are many image folders ), conf.calDir = 'data/caltech-101' ; ( I changed like this in phow_caltech101.m file) and I want to use categories ( accordion, airplanes, anchor, ant in caltech-101)

Comment: @Jang_Hyunwoong I added a comment to my answer that might help...

Comment: really appreciate your answer~! but there are problems... as you said I changed my folder name 'C:\VLFEAT\data\Caltech' and I've being changed line by line... could you send your e-mail address? I want to show my situation with pictures...thank you